# Giving a value of an Array back to the form

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I have a HTML code that looks kind of like this:

```
<input type="text" name="name[]" value="">
<input type="text" name="name[]" value="">
<input type="text" name="name[]" value="">
...
```

In PHP I would like to check if the value of any of those fields is set. If there is a value, then the value should be placed in the text field. How can I do this?

Comment: use isset() to check any of value is set or not on submit button click event

Comment: Are the values supposed to be stored in any variable ? (context variable, session, get, post ??)

Comment: @jilesh I can check the value using isset(), that's not a problem. But how to give the value back to the correct text field as a string?

Comment: mean you want to display your value in same text box ?

Comment: @jiboulex the values are getting sent via get method and are getting saved in sessions.

Comment: @jilesh exactly! This is a part of the validation. If the form cannot be sent, then the given values should still be there.

Comment: when do you exactly want to check the values? before submitting the form? or you send the values with ajax, process in the back-end, and then return the result back to your fields? i don't really get your question here, please help us.

Comment: you mean to say if my post is not submitted than all values are in same textbox as it is ? right ? you want to do validation ?

Comment: @rezashamdani after submitting the form you get directed to another page that checks if the values are set. If the user didn't fill in all required field, then he will get redirected back to the same page. I am not using Ajax.

Comment: @jilesh yes, this is exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: why not using ajax to check your validation in the backend, and then get the result to your need. that's much simpler to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this..

```
$name; //assign values to $name
$noOfFields = 3;
for($i = 0; $i < $noOfFields; $i++) {
    $value = !empty($name[$i]) ? $name[$i] : '';
    echo "<input type='text' name='name[]' value='$value'>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I must mention the text fields are getting created dynamically and this is why I am using an array for their names. So `$noOfFields = 3;` wouldn't be the best solution.